# How to append the telephone number to the country code in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create the script that will display the correct support telephone number for the user based on a country code from Active Directory

`$data = Get-ADUser $user -Properties * |  Select-Object DisplayName, Country`

it will display country code, for example, DE or NL depending on the user's location.

And I have around 100 telephone numbers saved as a variables:

````
$Belgium = "Dutch support (+32) 270891501, French support (+49) 231967383987)"
$Brasil = "(Brasil) +46 42 44647 120"
$Canada = "FR Support: ​*844-66-HELPU (+1 8446643578)"
$Czech = "*55555 (+420 2345 585555)"
$China = "*119 or (021)333974899" ```
````

How can I fit the user's country code to an appropriate country telephone number?
I was thinking about
 `if (($data.Country -like "*CN*")) {`

`Write-Host "$China" -ForegroundColor Green`

But it's time-consuming. maybe there is another way to adjust the script?

Comment: Why not store the information in a dictionary using the country code as key, instead of named variables? I’m assuming the AD data returns ISO values.

Comment: Are you looking through users to query? A calculated property, with a switch statement in it could be a simple solution without seeing your full code. What should your output/result look like? Can you update your question with that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar using regex to format telephone numbers correctly. This was due to some android corporate phones not dialling correctly if the user was looked up in the GAL.

```
#Get's all enabled users from the all users group which is populated nightly.
$usersall = Get-ADUser -Filter *

#Declare pattern match to remove non integer characters.
$numpattern = '[^0-9]'

#Iterate through users applying replaced value
$users | ForEach-Object {
    $regexedmobile = $_.mobile -replace $numpattern,''
    $userobj = [pscustomobject]@{
            samaccountname = $_.samaccountname
            oldmobile = $_.mobile
            intermediate = $regexedmobile

            newmobile = if ($regexedmobile.StartsWith('353')) {
                            $regexedmobile -replace '^3530|^353','+353' -replace '^(\+353)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})', '$1 $2 $3 $4'
                        }
                        #Rep of Ireland missing leading prefix
                        elseif ($regexedmobile.StartsWith('08')) {
                            $regexedmobile -replace '^08','+3538' -replace '^(\+353)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})', '$1 $2 $3 $4'
                        }
                        #UK with missing leading '0'
                        elseif ($regexedmobile.StartsWith('7')) {
                            $regexedmobile -replace '^7','+447' -replace '^(\+44)(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})', '$1 $2 $3 $4'
                        }
                        #India +91 International Dialling Code
                        elseif ($regexedmobile.StartsWith('91')) {
                            $regexedmobile -replace '^91','+91' -replace '^(\+91)(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})', '$1 $2 $3 $4'
                        }
                        #Sri Lanka International Dialling Code
                        elseif ($regexedmobile.StartsWith('0094')) {
                            $regexedmobile -replace '^0094','+94' -replace '^(\+94)(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})', '$1 $2 $3 $4'
                        }
                        #United States International Dialling Code
                        elseif ($regexedmobile.StartsWith('1')) {
                            $regexedmobile -replace '^1','+1' -replace '^(\+1)(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})', '$1 $2 $3 $4'
                        }
                        #Everything else (should be UK)
                        else {
                            $regexedmobile -replace '^0|^4400|^440|^44','+44' -replace '^(\+44)(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})', '$1 $2 $3 $4'
                        }
        }

        #If the users mobile field is not already populated then don't attempt to set a new mobile number.
        if ($null -ne $userobj.oldmobile) {
            Set-aduser -Identity $userobj.samaccountname -MobilePhone $userobj.newmobile -Credential $creds -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }

        #Return user object for validation
        $userobj

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of variables, you could create one hashtable where the country code is matched with the telephone number like this

```
$countries = @{
    'be' = 'Dutch support (+32) 270891501, French support (+49) 231967383987)'
    'br' = 'Brasil) +46 42 44647 120'
    'ca' = 'FR Support: ​*844-66-HELPU (+1 8446643578)'
    'cz' = '*55555 (+420 2345 585555)'
    'ch' = '*119 or (021)333974899'
}
```

You AD select could then use this hashtable in the select like this <sub>cudo's to Theo for the performance optimization</sub>

```
$data = Get-ADUser $user -Properties DisplayName, Country |
           Select-Object DisplayName, Country, @{n='tel';e={$countries[$_.Country]}}
```